# Background gradient repeating itself when document height is more than window height

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

I am looking to have a background gradient on my webpage. When the document height is less than the window height, I can see one single gradient throughout the page. However, when the document height is greater than the window height, the gradient starts repeating itself as I begin to scroll down. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of this and have a constant non-repeating gradient throughout the page.

Just to be clear, the window height is the actual height of the browser window and the document height is the actual height of the webpage with all the styling. Look at the following code:

```
html
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0% 0%;
  padding: 0% 0%;
  border: 0px;

  /* Background size */
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% auto;

  /* Background color */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background-color: #FFEE00;
}


body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0% auto;
  padding: 0% 0%;

  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;

  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I read an answer which suggested deleting the `height: 100%;` lines from both `html` and `body` classes, but when I do that, the gradient simply terminates where the document height ends. When the document height is less than window height, there is just white space in the remaining part of the window, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, and I've seen it work for others so give it a try, but where you use

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
```

in your html, add "fixed" to the end, so it looks like this:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300) fixed;
```

The rest of the code remains the same. Hope this helps!

~ Luke

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with `background-attachment: fixed;`

*ps: removed unecessary properties like `color:#000000` which is default.*

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);
  background: linear-gradient(#FFEE00, #FFD300);  
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
}
```

```html
<p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p><p>t</p>
```